# cannot use foreach more than one in view variable passed by controller

Tags: laravel, foreach

```
$std=Student::get();
return view(std, compact('std'));


@foreach($std as $std)
{Laravelp{$std->id}}
@endforeach
```

The above code work but the below code not work. If use the same variable in foreach more than one..?? can anyone tell me how can I use foreah more than one in view

```
$std=Student::get();
return view(std, compact('std'));

@foreach($std as $std)
{{$std->id}}
@endforeach

@foreach($std as $std)
  {{$std->id}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your collection with the loop variable. At the end of the loop, $std will be the last element from the original $std looped. change the variable name and it will work.

```php
@foreach($std as $singleStd)
{{$singleStd->id}}
@endforeach

@foreach($std as $singleStd)
  {{$singleStd->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @KashifShahzad if it fixed your issue, set it as the answer so the question doesn't stay open